# How long is it from the time a transaction is sent until it is viewable on pending transactions?

Tags: transactions, pending-transactions

How long does it take for a pending transaction to be viewable?
When it comes to viewing pending transactions I am referring to this:
https://etherscan.io/txsPending

Also, is there a faster way to view pending transactions? 
I am wondering what is the quickest way to view pending tx, and how fast is it.

Answer (score 3):

Often it will appear in seconds after you transmit it. If you are asking about "pending" transactions from an exchange wallet then it will appear shortly after they actually transmit the transaction to the network

Comment: Is there any way to have it appear in milliseconds?

Comment: @zunior sure if the node is extremely close. That question depends on latency

Answer (score 2):

I also depends of who emit the tx. etherscan have to sync with its peers. If the tx is from a node close to etherscan node, it's faster than if the tx have to go trough many nodes before reaching etherscan.
Longest time I experiences was about 20s to see it appear as pending, but most of the time it's much faster.