# How long does it take to reach consensus?

Tags: consensus, trust

I know it takes about 10 minutes on Bitcoin?

How long does it take to reach consensus on Ethereum so that I can start trusting a transaction?

EDIT:

- I am not asking about `pending` transactions. Pending would indicate that the transaction is in some `unconfirmed` state (non trustworthy). I want to know about fully confirmed transactions. Thanks.

Comment: maybe it can help you :  https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5699/how-long-is-it-from-the-time-a-transaction-is-sent-until-it-is-viewable-on-pendi

Comment: Hi, that is not helpful I think as it refers to pending transactions.

Comment: If you're looking for details on the block time (i.e. the amount of time to mine one block, containing a given number of transactions), see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/58/why-is-the-average-block-time-17-seconds

Comment: I disagree with this question being marked as a duplicate. He's asking about block confirmation time in addition to the number of blocks. The other question's answers only discuss the number of blocks, not the time.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://ethstats.net/, it's a great quick reference for block times.
As of writing, the average block time is about `20.18 seconds`.

That is, a block is confirmed approximately every `20.18 seconds`.

You probably only need one confirmation, so that is the required amount of time to trust the transaction. But you can always wait for more successive blocks to be confirmed just to be certain, in which case just multiply the average time by the desired number of blocks.

For more on the number of confirmations needed to trust a transaction, check out https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/8360/how-many-confirmations-do-i-need-to-ensure-a-transaction-is-successful